# command prompt after run grails 2.0.4 commands

Tags: grails, console, command, hidden, prompt

I have upgrade a grails project to the 2.0.4 version and now, after execute any grails command  the console the prompt is hidden and I can not see anything what I am typing. 
The problem happens in several machines I checked.

I am using ubuntu 12.0.4

Thank you all.